# case_when with multiple inner cases in R

Tags: r, dplyr, case

I want to write a `case_when` code in a `dplyr` pipeline. However, I am trying to add multiple cases within it.

For example: If a have the following data frame

| id | purchases |
| --- | --- |
| a | need |
| a | want |
| a | none |
| b | want |
| b | need |
| c | need |
| c | need |
| c | want |
| d | none |
| d | none |

I want to summarize the output so that case when the first 2 observations per each id are needs and case when the observation "none" is not put in consideration then put `yes` in a new column. If there's no need or want for a given id then `none`, else `no`

The output should be the following:

| id | output |
| --- | --- |
| a | no |
| b | no |
| c | yes |
| d | none |

**My code**

```
actions %>% group_by (id) %>% arrange(id) 
%>% summarise(output = case_when(first(purchases) == "need" & nth(purchases,2) =="need"~ "yes", "no"
```

I know the code is a bit messy, as I don't know who to add up the second condition of neglecting `none` observations when the cases would result in a `yes` or `no`

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to place your logic in a small function `f()`, which can then be applied to `purchases`, by `id`

```
f <- function(p) {
  if(p[1]==p[2] & (p[1] %in% c("need", "want"))) return("yes")
  ifelse(all(p=="none"), "none", "no")
}
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(output=f(purchases))
```

Output

```
  id    output
  <chr> <chr> 
1 a     no    
2 b     no    
3 c     yes   
4 d     none
```

The function checks if the first and second value of purchases are equal, and if they are either `need` or `want`; if so return "yes". Otherwise if all of `purchases` values are "none", return "none", else return "no".

Answer (score 0):

Try this to excludes `none` from top of `purchases`

```
fun <- function(x){
  if(all(x == "none")) return("none")
  for(i in 1:(length(x)-2)){
    if(x[1] == "none") x <- x[2:length(x)]
  }
  if(x[1] == x[2]) return("yes")
  else return("no")
}

df %>% group_by(id) %>%
   summarise(output = fun(purchases))
```

Comment: Thank you! what I’m seeking is that if purchases of an id are (none,need,need) in such order, the output would be a “yes” as i will only consider the sequence of need and want regardless of the none values. By doing so, i should count the 2 needs as the output 1 and output2 that i base my decision on. Would this code fulfill this?

Comment: Try this updated code

Comment: unfortunately, it still doesn't address the case as in the targeted situation, for example the first purchase is a none but it is followed by 2 needs, in this case, the output would be yes, but the code returns a no. I tried to start the condition in ```case_when``` as ```case_when(purchases %in% c("need","want")  & purchases[[1]]=="need" & purchases[[1]]==purchases[[2]])~"yes"``` and then proceed on the other two parts you wrote, however, it returned a long list with ids repeated multiple times without being grouped..

Comment: What about last update